# Can’t sculpt suddenly

Tags: sculpting, sculpt, sculpt-mode

I was happily sculpting away yesterday but when I opened blender today I couldn’t. It’s still a mesh, dyntopo is enabled, I’ve hit ctrl + A and applied rotation & scale. And still I can’t sculpt. How do I fix this? I only just started using blender.

heres the file:
[image]

Comment: Hello please show a screenshot or even share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You have masked out the object, that's why it's showing in black (or darkened) in _Sculpt Mode_ instead of white.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've masked the entire topology, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> to unmask and it will work again.

Comment: Too quick for me, I was going to post the same ;-) And wanted to add, if @moojoo wonders how that happened: since the complete object is masked, probably the (unmasked) object's mask was inverted with `Ctrl`+`I` so that now everything is masked. Of course inverting again would have removed the mask as well in this case.

Comment: Oh yes maybe it happened this way